# JS: How to concatenate variables inside appendChild()?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append a text node into a paragraph with values taken from its parent function's parameters.

```
function writeText(id, value, text) {

    //create our html elements

    var body = document.body;
    var par = document.createElement("p");
        par.className = id;
    this.value = document.createTextNode(value);
    this.text = document.createTextNode(text);

    //instantiate array that we will push value and text into

    textToInsert = [];
    textToInsert.push(this.value, this.text);

    //appends this.text and this.value inside the paragraph
    //and then appends that paragraph element into the body

    par.appendChild(textToInsert.join(' :'); //this does not work!
    par.appendChild(this.value+this.text); //this does not work!
    par.appendChild(this.value); //this works!
    body.appendChild(par);       
}
```

This code is giving me the error message

```
Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

So I take it that `join()` does not generate nodes. How can I concatenate two variables inside one `appendChild()`?

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit the code to explain the problem more thoroughly.

Comment: Your trying to append a string as a child, it needs to be a node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` does always generate strings. Your text nodes in the array will get stringified.

Instead, you will need to put plain strings in your array, and create only a single text node that you can append, with the concatenated content that you want.

```
var stringsToInsert = [value, text],
    stringToInsert = stringsToInsert.join(' :');

var textNode = document.createTextNode(stringToInsert);
par.appendChild(textNode);
```