# Converting string to DOM node (ul/li) in JavaScript with appendchild

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

I am trying to make use of `createElement`, `createTextNode` and `appendChild` to rewrite an outdated simple to-do list code example.

The code example requires the use of the `array` `join()` method so, unfortunately, this can't be removed. The old version just wrote the HTML for the `ul` list in code fragments.

I am unsure how to proceed where I have entered to comment at line 30 of the js: " need to render the tasks (from stringToInsert) as a list to `div id="output"` here "

I have referred to the following stackoverflow articles to help me rewrite the code:
[js-how-to-concatenate-variables-inside-appendchild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862951/js-how-to-concatenate-variables-inside-appendchild) -This example uses join() and appendChild but not list items.

[create-ul-and-li-elements-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351135/create-ul-and-li-elements-in-javascript)-
From that one, I copied the code from a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/so7qfg9p/) and put it into function createul() in my [example codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/qBZJVEj)

Once I have the function `addTask()` working `createul()` and it's associated HTML elements (such as the render list button) will be removed.

```js
// tasks.js #2
// This script manages a to-do list.

// Need a global variable:
var tasks = [];


function addTask() {
  'use strict';

  console.log("addTask started");
  // Get the task:
  var task = document.getElementById('task');

  // Reference to where the output goes:
  var output = document.getElementById('output');

  if (task.value) {
    tasks.push(task.value);
    // Update the page:
    //var message = '<h2>To-Do</h2>';

    var stringToInsert = tasks.join(' : ');
    console.log(stringToInsert);

    var taskUl = document.createElement('ul');
    taskUl.setAttribute('id', 'autoTask');

    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(taskUl);
    /* need to render the tasks (from stringToInsert) as a list to div id ="output" here */

    document.getElementById("task").value = '';
  }

  // Return false to prevent submission:
  return false;

} // End of addTask() function.




function createul() {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  ul.setAttribute('id', 'proList');

  var t, tt;
  productList = ['Electronics Watch', 'House wear Items', 'Kids wear', 'Women Fashion'];

  document.getElementById('renderList').appendChild(ul);
  productList.forEach(renderProductList);

  function renderProductList(element, index, arr) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.setAttribute('class', 'item');

    ul.appendChild(li);

    t = document.createTextNode(element);

    li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML + element;
  }
}

function init() {

  document.getElementById('renderbtn').addEventListener("click", createul);

  document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = addTask;

}


window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

```css
/* css (I have simplified this a little for this example and I am sorry I haven't cut it down further) */

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 2px #425955;
}


/* ----------- stylized ----------- */

h1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

p {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #666666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #BFBD9F;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  width: 140px;
  float: left;
}

select {
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 4px 2px;
  border: solid 1px #BFBD9F;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 2px 0 20px 10px;
}

input {
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 4px 2px;
  border: solid 1px #BFBD9F;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 2px 0 20px 10px;
}

#submit {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 31px;
  background: #F1F2D8;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#output {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="theForm">

  <div><label for="task">Task</label><input type="text" name="task" id="task" required></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Add It!" id="submit"><br>

  <button type="button" id="renderbtn">render list</button>

  <div id="renderList"></div>
  <div id="output"></div>
```

edit: I can just convert it back to an array with something like the following if there is no other way of doing it.

> var ar = stringToInsert.split(' : ');

or something based on:

stringToInsert.split(' : ').forEach ... or if that doesn't work I could try map()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509328/understanding-html-form-element-behavior/63509329#63509329 Returning `false` from the handler function doesn't prevent the submission of the form. That works only on an inline listener code.

Comment: I had a huge problem that the page would refresh to blank before I started using it but you are right it's not happening now when I comment it out. I will look into it further.

Comment: The original code example (not included) had it in the same place.

Comment: The fix is simple, if you don't want to submit a form, then don't submit it. Use a button type of button, and listen clicks on that button instead of listening submit event of the form.

Comment: 100% agree but I'm only allowed to rewrite the js here.

Comment: Then just include the event object argument in the argument list of the handler function, and call its `preventDefault` method. Notice also, that you can change the type of the button in JS too ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to show you a different approach that may help clear things up -

```js
function ul (nodes)
{ const e = document.createElement("ul")
  for (const n of nodes)
    e.appendChild(n)
  return e
}

function li (text)
{ const e = document.createElement("li")
  e.textContent = text
  return e
}

function onSubmit (event)
{ event.preventDefault()
  tasks.push(f.taskInput.value)
  f.taskInput.value = ""
  render()
}

function render ()
{ const newList = ul(tasks.map(li))
  f.firstChild.replaceWith(newList)
}

const tasks = [ "wash dishes", "sweep floors" ]  // <- initial tasks
const f = document.forms.main                    // <- html form
f.addButton.addEventListener("click", onSubmit)  // <- button listener
render()                                         // <- first render
```

```html
<h3>todo list</h3>
<form id="main">
  <ul></ul>
  <input name="taskInput" placeholder="example: paint fence">
  <button name="addButton">Add Task</button>
</form>
```

And here's a more modern approach using a DOM library like React -

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React
const { render } = ReactDOM

function TodoList ({ initTasks = [] })
{ const [ tasks, updateTasks ] =
    useState(initTasks)
    
  const inputEl =
    useRef(null)
  
  function onSubmit () {
    updateTasks([ ...tasks, inputEl.current.value ])
    inputEl.current.value = ""
  }
  
  return <div>
    <h3>todo list</h3>
    <ul>{tasks.map(t => <li children={t} />)}</ul>
    <input ref={inputEl} placeholder="ex: paint fence" />
    <button onClick={onSubmit}>add</button>
  </div>
}
 
render
  ( <TodoList initTasks={[ "wash dishes", "sweep floors" ]}/>
  , document.body
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This very impressive. Very clean and tidy code and I could learn a lot from it. Thank you.

Comment: I notice the tasks.map on line 22 in the render function. I was thinking of using the map array function if I couldn't use forEach and you give a better example then I could have ever imagined.

Comment: I'm delighted to help. Best of luck on your JS journey!

Comment: I noticed you are not using ';'.  

For example:<code>
    const tasks = [ ]  // <- initial tasks
    const f = document.forms.main                    // <- html form
    f.addButton.addEventListener("click", onSubmit)  // <- button listener
    render()    </code>


instead of:

<code>
    const tasks = [ ];  // <- initial tasks
    const f = document.forms.main;                    // <- html form
    f.addButton.addEventListener("click", onSubmit);  // <- button listener
    render()    
  </code>
Why is this?

Comment: Sharp eyes, nice catch! JavaScript has [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) and in most cases you totally don't need them. As a functional style advocate, when I need `;` in JS, I sense that as a problem that I need to restructure my program.